# Getting numbers after decimal Java

Tags: java, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange floating-point behaviour in a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327544/strange-floating-point-behaviour-in-a-java-program)
>   [Why does JSP/JSTL division by 1000 sometimes give remainder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002430/why-does-jsp-jstl-division-by-1000-sometimes-give-remainder)

I am trying to get the numbers after the decimal.
ex: `60.`4 -> `0.4`

Yet, when do

```
double a = 60.4 % 1;
```

it comes out to be `0.3999999999999986`.

Why is this? And how could it be fixed?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Read and digest : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.  Floating point primitives have limited precision in Java

Comment: @mcfinnigan or any language - see many duplicates here - but I can't seem to get a good query for tem

Comment: See also the helpful [floating point info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info) *"Many questions asked here about floating point math are about small inaccuracies in floating point arithmetic. To use the example from the excerpt, `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` might result in `0.300000001` instead of the expected `0.3`. Errors like these are caused by the way floating point numbers are represented in computers' memory. .."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use fixed-point types

```
BigDecimal src = new BigDecimal("60.4");
BigDecimal a = src.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to do your desired task.

Comment: Could you elaborate how?

Comment: NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");  in constructor you can specified the desired numbers'

Answer (score 0):

OK here is how you can do: [How to get the numbers after the decimal point? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166756/how-to-get-the-numbers-after-the-decimal-point-java)

I think this is exactly what you are looking for. So essentially you can use:

```
double x = d - Math.floor(d);
```

OR

[BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class for exact digits after decimal.